i am stuck here and unable to create build what should i do my flutter sdk is 3.19

Where:
Build file 'C:\Flutter App Dev\KD\destinationkolhapur\android\build.gradle' line: 19

What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.



Could not find method classpath() for arguments [com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.0] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
this was the issue

to make build beacuse i am unable to create build
enter image description here

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
